# UITextview: Place focus on becomefirstresponder

Tags: ios, uitextview, uitapgesturerecognizer, becomefirstresponder

I have a UITextView which becomes first responder by tapping. The code looks like this.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(editTextRecognizerTabbed:)];
recognizer.delegate = self;
recognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[self.textViewNotes addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

- (void) editTextRecognizerTabbed:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) aRecognizer;
{
    self.textViewNotes.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeNone;
    self.textViewNotes.editable = YES;
    [self.textViewNotes becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

So when the user taps on the textview, the textview becomes the first-responder and the focus is on the end of the text. I want place the focus on the tapped position in the Text.

Any idea?

Comment: why use UITapGestureRecognizer??

Comment: because the textview detect links and numbers. And it can't detect it when its editable. First time its uneditable and by tapping it gets editable.

Comment: Have you found a solution? Facing the same problem here

Comment: not at the moment...