# UITapGestureRecognizer not working for custom subclass of UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have created a custom subclass of UITextField, CustomTextView.

- I created a

  ```
  private var tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer()
  ```

  in the customTextView class
- In the initInView, I have the following code

  ```
  tapGesture.addTarget(self, action: "tapTextField:")
  self.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
  ```
- CustomTextView implements UIGestureRecognizerDelgate
- CustomTextView has a private func named tapTextField

Now when I use iOS simulator and click on the text field, the function tapTextField never gets called.

What am I missing here? I saw similar posts but none of them answer my question. I could not comment on those as I don't have reputation yet. So asking as a new question.

PS: Does this have to do with firstResponder being set? This is someone else's code I am working on, so I might have missed something. Let me know what I should look for

Related stack overflow questions:

- [Add UITapGestureRecognizer to UITextView without blocking textView touches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858908/add-uitapgesturerecognizer-to-uitextview-without-blocking-textview-touches)
- [UITextview: Place focus on becomefirstresponder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25175934/uitextview-place-focus-on-becomefirstresponder)

Comment: have you set the property `isUserInteractionEnabled` ?

Comment: I presume that the isUserInteractionEnabled is set to true by default as this is a UITextView that I am able to interact with. But I still set it to true explicitly and tried. No luck!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know swift, but try changing this `"tapTextField:"` to this `"tapTextField"` and make sure you don't have any arguments/parameters/whatever swift calls them in your `"tapTextField"` function.

Also, it looks like

`self.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)` should be `self.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try few things to debug the problem.

1> Make sure there is no mistake of `tapTextField` and `tapTextField:` i.e. you are adding selector with argument but you have implemented same method without any argument.

2> Make sure no any other transparent view obscuring your custom `uitextfield`. 
3> print `po yourTextFieldName` in the xcode console to see whether actually your textfield has any gesture recognizer added in it or not.

Hope this helps